# Side menu animation

Tags: animation, menu, slide

Anybody knows how to do this menu animation? :
[text](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EMRN_VeQwVLkjAMRu510OFSnMUltlOrW/preview)
(from BBVA APP, they have the same for both android and iOS app).

Is it custom? Or does it exists any library? (I didn't seen it in material design or others for now).

Thanks!